# C# Object List to String List

Tags: c#, object, casting, type-conversion

[image: object list]

I have `List<object>` that seems above, I want to convert it to `List<string>`.

How can I convert it ?

I need `List<string>` that has 6 items (11:00,13:45,.... etc)

Comment: You don't have a `List<object>` you have a `object[]` of size 6.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, true, but most of the solutions below should still work. Array has IEnumerable.

Comment: seances is List<object>, and first index of seances is object[]. I need these items.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen if there is an object that's not a string in there?  Should it be excluded, should an exception be thrown, or what?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var mylist = myObjectList.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString());
```

**Edit**

```
  var mylist = myObjectList.ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));
```

thanks  Scott Chamberlain

To get first array of objects

```
var mylist = (myObjectList.First() as object[]).ToList()
                .ConvertAll(x=>Convert.ToString(x));
```

To add rest to the list.

```
mylist.AddRange(mylist.GetRange(1,myObjectList.Count-2).ConvertAll(x=>Convert.ToString(x)));
```

Comment: Huh, I never knew about `ConvertAll`. However you should use `Convert.ToString(x)` as that will check if the class supports [`IConvertable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) and if not then it falls back to `.ToString()`

Answer (score 6):

```
var stringList = yourObjectList.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

Remember to add the namespace `System.Linq;`

The OfType is needed to convert the array to an `array<T>` which is necessary in order to use it with LINQ

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.String'

Comment: DO you perhaps have an array as one of your entries?

Comment: @MelihMucuk, what do you have for `yourObjectList`? It should be `seanceInfo.theatre[i].seances[0]`.

Comment: there is no options for seanceInfo.theatre[i].seances[0] like Select or any LINQ expression.

Comment: Make sure the System.Linq using statement is added

Comment: System.Linq added. And I'm using .net 4.0. There is no options for it. I updated my question please check it out.

Comment: Ok, updated. It is just an object array - not an array of T which is needed for Linq to work

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
List<string> stringlist = objectList.Cast<string>()
                                    .ToList();
```

If you're not certain about those elements are strings you can use `Select`

```
List<string> stringlist = objectList.Select(x=> x.ToString())
                                    .ToList();
```

To avoid `NullReferenceException` in case of null values try the following

```
List<string> stringlist = objectList.Where(x=> x != null)
                                    .Select(x=> x.ToString())
                                    .ToList();
```

Comment: The second will fail on `null` values.

Comment: @Servy I anticipated this, got it from you. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ this is fairly easy. If you are sure they are all strings you can simply do

```
int i = //Some code that sets i, like a for loop
var oldList = seanceInfo.theatre[i].seances;
List<string> newList = oldList.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

If you are not sure all of the objects are strings you need to perform some kind of conversion, however that is just as easy

```
List<string> newList = oldList.Select(o => Convert.ToString(o)).ToList();
```

---

From your comment: "*seances is `List<object>`, and first index of seances is `object[]`. I need these items.*", I think what you *really* want may be a `SelectMany`

```
List<string> info = seanceInfo.theatre.SelectMany(x => x.seances).Select(x => Convert.ToString(x)).ToList();
```

This will take each seance in each theater and combine it in to one master list.

Comment: It works but I need listed items in index of [0]. Your solution doesn't give to me these items.

Comment: @MelihMucuk yes it does, See my updated version where I replaced the `\\...`

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.String'

Comment: @MelihMucuk we all kinda figured that out already and every answer here is trying to give that to you. Update your answer instead with actual code showing what you have tried with our various implmentations. You likely made a error copying from this website to your code and if we could see what you wrote it would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast it using LinQ.

```
myObjectList.Cast<string>();
```

Or filter all non-string

```
myObjectList.OfType<string>();
```

Comment: No such method `TypeOf`

Comment: I would be careful with `OfType`. It really acts as a `where` statement looking for objects that are the given type, and weeds out the ones that are not. If for some (dumb) reason you have more than 2 types in your list, or your types are not string to begin with, it will select less.

Answer (score -4):

Casting like :

```
var list = (List<String>) listObjects.
```

Comment: Ok, I'm calling your bluff. That does not compile.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to try out code like this before posting it as an answer.